# Sort array of strings by length (words) c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a function to generate all sub sequences of a word, and I'm saving that sub sequences in a structure, array of strings. Now i want to sort each array, the shortest to longest sub sequence. I'm trying to use `STD sort()`, but i can not figure it out how can i use this in my case. Any susgestion?

**Strucuture and Function**

```
struct palavras{
    char palavra[1001];
    char final[1001];
    string store[1000];
    int numero;
}p[1001];

void encontra(const char *s, int n)
{
    string str;
    int nn=0;
    while(*s)
    {
        int x=0;
        while(*(s + x))
        {
            for(int y = 0; y <= x; y++)
                str+=s[y];
                p[n].store[nn]=str;
                nn+=1;
                str.clear();
            x++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    p[n].numero=nn;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one version of `std::sort` that accepts a "comparator", so only thing you need to do is to define a comparator that compares strings by their length.

```
struct compare_length {
    bool operator()(const std::string &l, const std::string &r) const {
        return l.size()<r.size();
    }
};
```

Then you can use this comparator to sort your word array:

```
std::sort(store, store+n, compare_length());
```

In C++11 you can even use lambda to make it one-liner:

```
std::sort(store, store+n, [](const std::string &l, const std::string &r) { return l.size()<r.size(); });
```

Comment: Thanks. Its what i want!

Comment: I have another doubt. How can i sort alphabetically the elements with same lenght? (keeping the lenght sort) ?

Comment: to sort also by alphabetic order: bool operator()(const std::string &l, const std::string &r) const
{
 if(l.size() != r.size()) 
  return l.size()<r.size();
 else
  return l < r;  
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::sort`:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec{ "a", "abcd", "abc", "ab" };
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2) {return s1.size() < s2.size(); });
```

Comment: sort(p[n].store.begin(), p[n].store.end(), [](string s1, string s2) {return s1.size() < s2.size(); }); -> I'm trying like this, and its not working. I'm not using a vector

Comment: I have another doubt. How can i sort alphabetically the elements with same lenght? (keeping the lenght sort) ?

Comment: You can add another condition in the comparator function:`if (s1.size() == s2.size())  return s1 < s2; else return s1.size() < s2.size();`